# Silverlight Media Element not working

Tags: silverlight, xaml, video

I've this XAML tag:

```
<MediaElement Source="../Assets/videos/braco_1.wmv" AutoPlay="True" />
```

But this is not working, i can't display the video.
The given url is correct, so i can't find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in Source you are giving.Try giving the source like this

```
Source="/Application_Name;component/Assets/videos/braco_1.wmv"
```

If you still find the problem put you video file in the `root directory` and give only the filename and check.

Here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source.aspx

and also look into this [play video in silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421792/play-video-in-silverlight)